# Windows on logical partition

Tags: windows-xp, boot, partitioning

First of all, I know, me stupid for not checking.

I had the following partition system (guessing looking at current situation, for it's not me, who set up so idiotically):

```
/dev/sda1: Dell Utility
/dev/sda2: Recovery (10GB)
/dev/sda5: Windows XP (~290GB)
```

And I needed `Lubuntu` on the PC. I copied out everything from **Recovery** partition (`/dev/sda2`) and installed `Lubuntu` there. I made two (three) mistakes:

1. Didn't simply shrink `/dev/sda5`
2. Didn't check what **Recovery** partition was used for (it most probs contained Windows bootloader in addition to everything else, despite having `D` letter)
3. Didn't check where were **Windows XP** (for I know that Windows don't like to be on logical partitions) - I only checked partitions size.

Output of `lsblk` from Lubuntu:

```
sda      8:0    0 298,1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  39,2M  0 part      (Label: DellUtility)
├─sda2   8:2    0    10G  0 part /    (Lubuntu)
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part      (blkid does not list this one, educated guess would be grub)
├─sda4   8:4    0    10G  0 part      (This one I've created myself, planning to put new "Recovery" here)
├─sda5   8:5    0 273,4G  0 part      (Windows XP C:/ disk)
└─sda6   8:6    0   4,7G  0 part      (Swap I created when creating 10GB one; I know it's not used now)
```

Lubuntu works flawlessly, as expected.

Windows XP do not boot.

What have I tried:

1. Dummy copying all files that had been in Recovery partition to a newly created **primary** partition, give it **boot** flag with `gparted` and using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to update grub entries. I got `Windows XP (on /dev/sda5)` menu entry that hangs with blinking underscore in top left corner.
2. Downloading Windows XP disk image, use [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to burn it to USB and boot from it. It reads some things, says "Starting Windows XP" and then crashes "to prevent damage to [my] computer".
3. Banging my head to wall.
4. Turning Windows XP partition into primary via `fixparts` then `boot-repair`. Partition number has changed, still hangs. I ahve made sure I marked it as active (boot) partition, so really no bootloader there.

Can I boot my beloved Windows XP with all programs still there? I still have the contents of the "Recovery" partition.
I'd prefer to avoid using DVD for I don't have it (and I'm lazy to go searching for `DVD+RW`).

I have Ubuntu and Windows 8 at my possession.

Comment: Installing Windows 8 if I knew for sure that programs will still work would be better solution than none. Official requirements are met.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up copying everything to external hard and reformatting whole drive, for both Windows XP and Windows 8 setup restarted PC and halted.

I guess, something in Dell Utility partition was interfering.